# How can I point out a specific location in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

How can I point out a specific location in Google Maps? I tried to look at the questions before but I didn't find anything that could "help" me.

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.393584, 15.566656),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {       
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

(Ignore the `margin` and `float`), it does zoom in onto the location but how can I add a pointer to it? Would an image of a pointer do? Might be a newbie question, but thanks if you can help me.

Comment: google [maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) (scroll down and click on markers)

Comment: @JaromandaX Should I just put the marker code into my script, or where should I put it?

Comment: yes, personally, I'd put javascript code in a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `Marker` Object.
For the **Label** you can use [maplabel.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label)

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.393584, 15.566656),
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  // MARKER:
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    label: "G",
    map: map
  });
  
  // LABEL:
  var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
    text: "Go here!",
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    fontSize: 22,
    align: 'center'
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {       
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/src/maplabel.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: @JamesSnowy use: `label:"A"` if you want only one character, otherwise this might help: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the google maps API like this, I would personally use Polymer for google-elements like google-map etc.

Polymer is all about web-components, it's very simple, clean & easy to use.

Example of how the google maps API would work with a Polymer element

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"
      draggable="true" title="This is a title"></google-map-marker>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911"></google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

It's amazingly simple and flexible.

Here's the link to the documentation if you're interested:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map